# How to have roboto font in bookdown::pdf_document2?

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown, roboto

Anyone suggestions on how to get roboto font in bookdown::pdf_document2?
The code below works fine, when I change the font to Roboto it does not, see also picture. The Roboto and the Comic Sans MS font are in my c:\Windows\Fonts, I use Miktex for pdf-ing. Thanks!

```
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fontspec}
- \setmainfont{Comic Sans MS}
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: false
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

# Title
This is some text.  
This is some more text.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `\usepackage{roboto}`. See [README](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/roboto) of the package for further detailed usage. If you knit the document without `roboto` package, programmes for knitting documents using LaTeX (e.g. R's `tinytex` or even MikTeX) will automatically install the missing package(s). See the [relevant page](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-latex-pkgs.html) of *R Markdown Cookbook*.

## To make specific texts san serif

```
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{roboto}
# - \usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto} # To make every texts san serif
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: false
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

# Title

This is some text.  
This is some more text.

`\textsf{This is a san serif text.}`{=latex}
```

[image]

## To make every texts san serif

```
---
header-includes:
#- \usepackage{roboto}
- \usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto} # To make every texts san serif
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: false
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

# Title

This is some text.  
This is some more text.

`\textsf{This is a san serif text.}`{=latex}
```

[image]